Watery Gummies - Yuk!
I have a similar problem as another post but after reading through the suggestions, I think I found part of what I did wrong but not everything.
My recipe was simple:

1 tbsp sugar
2 tbsp Gelatin unflavored
One small pack jello
1/2 cup water.

My first mistake was my heat was too high. The gelatin stuck to the side of the sauce pan.
My second mistake was the drying process. That was not mentioned in my recipe.
I put my gummies in a citric acid / sugar mixture but immediately put them in the refrigerator. This is where things went very wrong. When I looked at them after about an hour, my gummies were in a pool of goo.
Should I not refrigerate the gummies?
Were the heat too high with the gelatin stuck to the side of the saucepan and the ratio of water to bloomed gelatin the cause for the liquefication?
Thx!
